# Is it OK to return as object when using generics?

Tags: vb.net, generics, interface

I'm trying to get a grasp on generics and interfaces. Are there performance implications for accepting a generic and returning an object?

```
Public Interface Interface1
    Sub load(reader As SqlDataReader)
End Interface

Public Interface Interface2    
    Function insert(Of T)(ByVal record As T) As Object              
End Interface
```

The object returned would need access to the `load()` method.

Comment: Is there a reason you wouldn't just specify Interface1 explicitly - `Function insert(Of T)(record as T) as Interface1`

Comment: No, there isn't. It was just a thought.